# Hover Navigation Link - Change Logo Image

Tags: jquery, css, image, hover

I have a logo header and 5 links below it as main navigation. I want to substitue the main logo image with a color variation of the logo every time a link is hovered. So there would be 5 different color logos for each of the links. Hover a link and the logo would appear to change color.

I'm finding a lot of solutions for hover image to change another image and hover link to make an image appear, but nothing that's helping me.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically have you looked at and why didn't it help you?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".link").hover(function(){
  $("#header").attr("src","/images/"+$(this).attr("class").split(" ")[1]+"Logo.png");
},function(){
  $("#header").attr("src","/images/defaultLogo.png");
})
```

```
<a class="link red" href="home.htm">home</a>
<a class="link blue" href="products.htm">products</a>
<a class="link green" href="about.htm">about</a>
<a class="link yellow" href="contact.htm">contact</a>
```

That's how I'd do it.